# Cannot achieve Sklearn kMeans clusters where one classification dominates

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

Recently I've been experimenting with Sklearn's kMeans clustering algorithm. Currently, I've created a dataset, using the `make_circles` function, of a small circle of points within a large circle of points. However, it seems no matter what I try I cannot fit and predict a result which is not evenly split between two clusters. What've I've tried to do is create such radical initial centroids so that when I predict on the dataset there will only be one cluster containing all the points while another has no points within it at all. Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X, y = make_circles((200,50), noise=.05, random_state=0, factor=0.2)
means = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init=[[-1000,1000], [0,0]]).fit_predict(X)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=means, s=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

As you can see I want to make a big circle of 200 points encompassing a smaller circle with 50 points with the initial centroids being (-1000,1000) and (0,0). It would make sense (at least to me) that no matter how many iterations you do all the points would be attributed to the cluster originating from the (0,0) and no points would be part of the cluster starting from the point (-1000,1000) because of the sheer distance it's from the points.

This doesn't seem to be the case as the scatterplot shows an even split of two colors. Could somebody explain what's going on and how I can resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the sklearn User Guide [section 2.3](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) has a nice visual summary of how KMeans and other clustering algorithms perform on concentric circular clusters:

[image]

KMeans assumes clusters are spherical and have equal variance, which doesn't hold for concentric clusters. DBSCAN, on the other hand, is density-based and discerns clusters based on density rather than distance. I think it's a case of trying different clustering techniques and seeing which play well with your data.